# Getting error while installing mysqlclient on Mac ( Terminal )

Tags: python, mysql, django, terminal

I am trying to install mysqlclient on my mac to connect MySQL database to django for a website and I always face an error for the command :

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0). ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
```

I even tried installing specific versions of mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient==2.0.0
```

But I still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check output:

```
mysql_config --libs
```

If no errors try these commands (otherwise install mysql):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install mysqlclient==2.0.0
```

Comment: This gives me a different error now.

`note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.`

`python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
`

Comment: Please post this new error here.

Comment: `python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/61/zk1c33w1157_nq5xrr896y240000gn/T/pip-install-7_rsex5w/mysqlclient_c22fdb33af75425b85504548901c29b0/setup.py", line 15, in <module>`

Comment: Can you check what are your python and pip versions?

Comment: `pip 22.0.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

Python = 3.9
Pip = 22.0.3

Comment: Try upgrade setuptools:
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: After upgrading setuptools, I still get the same error. 

`note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.`

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed? 
Can you run command: 

"mysql_config --libs"

What is output?

Comment: I do have MySQL installed. But mysql_config --libs doesn't work

`zsh: command not found: mysql_config`

Comment: You should have installed the following packages: mysql-server, libmysqlclient-dev (or libmariadbclient-dev)

Comment: i can't get that to work either, That isn't installing either.